# Why is ToRadicals[] not able to handle all cases? Is there a workaround?

Tags: equation-solving, functions, symbolic, algebraic-manipulation, expression-manipulation

The documentation for the function [`ToRadicals`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ToRadicals.html) says:

> ♦ There are some cases in which expressions involving radicals can in principle be given, but `ToRadicals` cannot find them.

I'm concerned only with cases where the argument to `ToRadicals` is a single `Root` object with a single polynomial function with integer coefficients and no parameters, and an explicit root index.

---

Here is an example when *Mathematica* cannot find an expression in radicals:

```
ToRadicals[Root[-1 - #1^2 - #1^3 + #1^4 + #1^6 &, 2]]
```

But actually the expression exists:
$$\frac1{\sqrt[3]{36}}\left(\frac3{\sqrt{\beta\phantom{.}}}+\frac\beta2\right),\ \text{where}\ \beta=\sqrt[3]{2\,\ \alpha}-8\sqrt[3]{\frac3\alpha\phantom{}},\ \alpha=9+\sqrt{849}.$$

---

Another example is

```
ToRadicals[Root[6 + 25 #1 - 25 #1^3 + 5 #1^5 &, 5]]
```

where the expression in radicals is
$$\sqrt[5]{\frac{-3+4\sqrt{-1}}5}+\sqrt[5]{\frac{-3-4\sqrt{-1}}5}$$

---

What is the nature of this restriction? Is the problem known to be undecidable in general? Or is it extremely computationally expensive?

Can we write an implementation of `ToRadicals` that is able to find an expression in radicals in all cases when it is possible? Or, at least, in much more cases then the built-in `ToRadicals` does?

Comment: Requires computational Galois theory in general. It's computationally expensive and probably nowhere implemented in Mathematica.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
rad = Root[-1 - #^2 - #^3 + #^4 + #^6 &, 2];
poly = rad[[1]][x]
PolynomialRemainder[poly, x^2 + a x + b, x]
a /. SolveAlways[% == 0, x];
Factor[poly, Extension -> %[[1]]];
x /. Solve[% == 0, x];
ans = Select[%, N[# == rad] &] // First // Simplify
```

> -1 - x^2 - x^3 + x^4 + x^6
>
> -1 + b- a b- a^2 b- a^4 b + b^2 + 
>    3 a^2 b^2 - b^3 + (a - a^2 - a^3 - a^5 + b + 2 a b + 4 a^3 b - 3 a b^2) x
>
> 1/12 (8 3^(2/3) (2/(-9 + Sqrt[849]))^(1/3) - 
>      2^(2/3) (3 (-9 + Sqrt[849]))^(1/3) + Sqrt[
>      2 (24 + 96 3^(1/3) (2/(-9 + Sqrt[849]))^(2/3) + 
>         2^(1/3) (3 (-9 + Sqrt[849]))^(2/3))])

Comment: This approach works on my original example, but fails to express `Root[6 + 25 # - 25 #^3 + 5 #^5 &, 5]` in radicals. But actually it is $\sqrt[5]{\frac{-3+4\sqrt{-1}}5}+\sqrt[5]{\frac{-3-4\sqrt{-1}}5}$.

Answer (score 4):

We can solve your quintic by substituting $x = y + \frac{1}{y}$. This gives the equation $5y^5 + 6 + \frac{5}{y^5} = 0$, which is quadratic in $y^5$.

```
In[1]:= Module[{poly, y, sol},
   poly = 6 + 25x - 25x^3 + 5x^5;
   sol = y + 1/y /. Solve[0 == poly /. x -> y+1/y, y];
   Union[Select[sol, Chop[N[poly /. x -> #]] == 0&], SameTest -> (N[#1] == N[#2]&)]
]

Out[1]= {
   1/(-(3/5)-(4 I)/5)^(1/5)+(-(3/5)-(4 I)/5)^(1/5),
   (-1)^(4/5)/(-(3/5)-(4 I)/5)^(1/5)-(-1)^(1/5) (-(3/5)-(4 I)/5)^(1/5),
   -((-1)^(3/5)/(-(3/5)-(4 I)/5)^(1/5))+(-1)^(2/5) (-(3/5)-(4 I)/5)^(1/5),
   (-1)^(2/5)/(-(3/5)-(4 I)/5)^(1/5)-(-1)^(3/5) (-(3/5)-(4 I)/5)^(1/5),
   -((-5)^(1/5)/(-3-4 I)^(1/5))+(-1)^(4/5) (-(3/5)-(4 I)/5)^(1/5)
}
```

I got lucky here trying to sub $x = y + \frac{a}{y}$. Here's *Mathematica* code, written by Michael Trott, to solve any quintic solvable in radicals. It's old code, so some modifications will need to be made. *It would be really cool if this was incorporated into* `ToRadicals`!

http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/158/

Unfortunately, I'm unable to get it to solve your quintic though!

**Edit**

I think `ToRadicals` is generally intended for cubics and quartics. Trying to find roots of simple quintics such as $(x+1)^5+2$ in terms of radicals doesn't even seem to work out.

```
In[2]:= Solve[3 + 5 x + 10 x^2 + 10 x^3 + 5 x^4 + x^5 == 0, x] // ToRadicals

Out[2]= {
   {x -> Root[3 + 5 #1 + 10 #1^2 + 10 #1^3 + 5 #1^4 + #1^5 &, 1]}, 
   {x -> Root[3 + 5 #1 + 10 #1^2 + 10 #1^3 + 5 #1^4 + #1^5 &, 2]},
   {x -> Root[3 + 5 #1 + 10 #1^2 + 10 #1^3 + 5 #1^4 + #1^5 &, 3]},
   {x -> Root[3 + 5 #1 + 10 #1^2 + 10 #1^3 + 5 #1^4 + #1^5 &, 4]},
   {x -> Root[3 + 5 #1 + 10 #1^2 + 10 #1^3 + 5 #1^4 + #1^5 &, 5]}
}
```